# Переключение Scene в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Пишу первую программу на JavaFx и возникла такая проблема

Идея: В Stage добавил сцену типа BorderPane, в верхней части разместил ComboBox, который содержит в себе список различного функционала, а в центральной части должен подгружаться AnchorPane, в котором содержится определённый функционал (текстовые поля, кнопки и т.д.). То есть по идеи при выборе в ComboBox определённого элемента списка в центральную часть BorderPane должен выводиться определённый AnchorPane, то есть происходить смена этих самых AnchorPane (каждый создан в отдельном fxml файле).

Проблема: не знаю как реализовать переключение, написал код, который вызывает разные методы при смене элемента в ComboBox, но если при первоначальной загрузке не был вызван метод, отвечающий за добавление AnchorPane в BorderPane, то все дальнейшие попытки сделать это обвенчаются провалом с ошибкой NullPointerException.

Подскажите, как реализовать данную задумку, возможно всё это стоит сделать как то иначе, просто я особо не нашёл ответа в сети как это сделать (возможно плохо искал). Главное чтобы при смене элемента в ComboBox менялся функционал (функционал работает по типу ввод, обработка данных, вывод).

Comment: Я так понимаю вопрос в том, что бы написать код за вас?

Comment: "Если при первоначальной загрузке не был вызван метод" - ну так вызовите, в чём-то проблема? Или может вам нужно обработать эту ситуацию, выкинув окошко "Этот метод можно вызывать только после нажатия кнопки блаблабла" И вообще, вы говорите "написал код" - ну так покажите. В вопрос есть смысл добавить минимально воспроизводимый пример..